# Need to use math formula to determine cell reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to be able to use this formula but have the range changed based on the value in another cell.

```
SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(B5:B15,B5:B15)
```

For example, if the macro is written as:

```
SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(B5:B(15-k3),B5:B(15-k3))
```

I would pass the value k3=2 to get:

```
SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(B5:B13,B5:B13)
```

Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `INDEX` like this:

`=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(B5:INDEX(B:B,15-K3),B5:INDEX(B:B,15-K3))`

INDEX is usually preferable to using `INDIRECT` which is an alternative way to achieve this

Comment: why is INDEX preferred over INDIRECT?

Comment: Two reasons - INDIRECT is a "volatile" function which means that it re-calculates every time the worksheet is re-calculated, which can slow down your calculations (although it won't have any significant effect for one formula). Also if you use INDIRECT you need to "hardcode" the column letter like "B", which is a problem if you delete or add columns (OFFSET is another alternative but that, too, is volatile)

Comment: I guess I am confused, why would you **not** want your functions to be `volatile`?  If they do not re-calculate every time then when are `non-volatile` functions calculated?

Comment: Volatile functions re-calculate even if their precedents don't change, unlike non-volatile functions. Volatility can significantly increase Excel's calculation time